# error: request for member ... which is of non-class type ‘char’

Tags: c++

When I try to run this code:

```
    if  (strcmp(input, "GET")==0) {
      //Ask which item they want to get
      cout << "Which item? " << endl;
      char itemInput[20];
      cin.get(itemInput, 20);
      char* itemName = itemInput;
      //Create an iterator to go through the item vector in the room
      vector<item*>::iterator it;
      for (it = currentRoom->getItems()->begin(); it != currentRoom->getItems()->end(); it++) {
    //If the inputted item matches an item in the vector
    if (strcmp((*it)->itemName, itemInput)==0) {
      //Add the item to the inventory vector
      i->push_back(*it);
      //Remove the item from the room
      currentRoom->getItems()->erase(it);
    }
  }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘* currentRoom->room::getItems()’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
       for (it = currentRoom->getItems()->begin(); it != currentRoom->getItems()->end(); it++) {
                          ^~~~~
error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘* currentRoom->room::getItems()’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
       for (it = currentRoom->getItems()->begin(); it != currentRoom->getItems()->end(); it++) {
                                                                                  ^~~
error: request for member ‘erase’ in ‘* currentRoom->room::getItems()’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
    currentRoom->getItems()->erase(it);
                             ^~~~~
error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘* currentRoom->room::getItems()’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
    currentRoom->getItems()->push_back(*it);
```

`i` is a vector of items, and here is the code for the getItems() method

```
char* room::getItems() {
  //Creates an iterator to go through the item vector in the rooms
  vector<item*>::iterator it;
  for (it = roomItem->begin(); it != roomItem->end(); it++) {
    cout << (*it)->itemName << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getItems` is declared as returning a `char *`.  The caller is expecting it to return a `vector<item *>`.  This causes compilation problem because while a vector has a `begin` method, a character does not.

Your implementation of `getItems` does not do what the name implies, and in any case it does not actually return anything.

You'll need to properly implement `getItems`, with the correct return type.